# writeFile from array to new line won't work

Tags: javascript, node.js, fs

```
const file = [1,2,3]
fs.writeFile(path, file.join(',') + '\n')
```

and I still see the saved file content is 1,2,3

How can I save each of the array in a new line like so?

```
1
2
3
```

Answer (score 4):

You're joining your array with commas, then adding a new line at the end. You want to change your join: `fs.writeFile(path, file.join('\n'))`